# Solution for typesetting interviews in LaTeX?

Tags: packages, typography

Are there any packages for typesetting interviews in LaTeX?

Of course, I could manually format all the text but I am sure that there are typographical rules for interview sections that I would probably miss.

Comment: If you need to write down the interview, which has been recorded, you can save much time and effort by using a dictation system, the basic version often is good enough. You listen to your recording and repeat the words into the microphone.

Answer (score 8):

I not sure if you are searching for a package like `dramatist` or `dialogue`. Please look also at CTAN in topics  [drama-script](https://ctan.org/topic/drama-script) and [quotation](https://ctan.org/topic/quotation) for some others related packages.

Comment: the url became invalid at some time. Has the reference project/page moved or did it cease to exist?

Comment: @kmindi Updated

Comment: @Fran Link is broken again

Comment: @RadonRosborough  All texcatalogue.ctan.org page are down . I changed the link to to ctan.org topics.